# Changing a BOOL when UIView is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, boolean

I am trying to setup a change to a `UIView` when it is touched. It is a subclass to `UIView` and has a property `BOOL` which is called 'isSelected'.

When the view is created we set it to YES:

```
self.isSelected = YES;
```

When the view is touched the following runs:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (self.isSelected) {
        self.isSelected = NO;
    } else if (!self.isSelected) {
        self.isSelected = YES;
    }
```

The issue seems to be that the isSelected seems to always been seen as NO instead of YES. What is the best way to do this.

EDIT: Log out

```
-(void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)isSelected {
    NSLog(@"isselected chaned to: %@",isSelected ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

Comment: FYI - you can replace those 4 lines with 1: `self.iSSelected = !self.isSelected;`. That will toggle the value.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy - I have added an EDIT which shows me logging out the change to isSelected. I have changed those lines to your suggestion. I notice that the change is always showing as YES. Is something not correct? I need this to be logged correctly so I can call a different update method when it is changed to YES/NO from this view directly or when the VC they reside on update the isSelected for these too. Thanks

Comment: If you are going to override the `setIsSelected:` method, it would help to set the value in the method.

Comment: You are right @rmaddy - What should be in this default method? Is this the correct approach to change the background/borer when this property is changed or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overridden `setIsSelected:` method never updates the value. You want:

```
-(void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)isSelected {
    _isSelected = isSelected;
    NSLog(@"isselected chaned to: %@",isSelected ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```